# Installing Quartus (Altera|Intel, v13.1) with 32 bit Libraries

Tags: 16.04, bash, software-installation, scripts, intel

I'm installing the Quartus software suite via the `setup.sh` file. Originally trying to `chmod`, I attempted to run the shell executable

via  `./setup.sh`

```
bash: ./setup.sh: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

then via `sudo ./setup.sh`.

```
sudo: unable to execute ./setup.sh: No such file or directory
```

Finally, using the `sudo bash setup.sh` command in terminal gives a useful error:

```
You must have the 32-bit compatibility libraries installed for the Quartus II installer and software to operate properly.
setup.sh: line 106: /home/matt/Downloads/Software Packages/Quartus-web-13.1.0.162-linux/components/QuartusSetupWeb-13.1.0.162.run: Permission denied
setup.sh: line 106: exec: /home/matt/Downloads/Software Packages/Quartus-web-13.1.0.162-linux/components/QuartusSetupWeb-13.1.0.162.run: cannot execute: Permission denied`
```

I've gone and attempted to download these libraries, as listed in the [Quartus  Online Install & Licensing Manual](https://www.altera.com/content/altera-www/global/en_us/index/documentation/esc1425946071433.html#mwh1410890908550). That involves installing the following pre-requisite libraries, listed respectively for the ModelSim software (64 bit) and as well as for Quartus (32bit dependence):

`sudo apt-get install`

- unixodbc unixodbc-dev libncurses-dev libzmq3-dev libxext6 libasound2 libxml2 libx11-6 libxtst6 libedit-dev libxft-dev libxi6
- libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxft-dev:i386 libxrender-dev:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386

Which provides the following information:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'libncurses-dev'
libasound2 is already the newest version (1.1.0-0ubuntu1).
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1).
libx11-6 is already the newest version (2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2).
libxext6 is already the newest version (2:1.3.3-1).
libxi6 is already the newest version (2:1.7.6-1).
libxtst6 is already the newest version (2:1.2.2-1).
unixodbc is already the newest version (2.3.1-4.1).
unixodbc-dev is already the newest version (2.3.1-4.1).
libx11-6:i386 is already the newest version (2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2).
libxau6:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.0.8-1).
libxdmcp6:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.1.2-1.1).
libxext6:i386 is already the newest version (2:1.3.3-1).
libxft-dev:i386 is already the newest version (2.3.2-1).
libxrender-dev:i386 is already the newest version (1:0.9.9-0ubuntu1).
libxt6:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.1.5-0ubuntu1).
libxtst6:i386 is already the newest version (2:1.2.2-1).
libzmq3-dev is already the newest version (4.1.4-7).
libxml2 is already the newest version (2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libxft-dev : Conflicts: libxft-dev:i386 but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
 libxft-dev:i386 : Conflicts: libxft-dev but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

No matter which architecture `libxft` I install, the same error message occurs for the shell executable when running with with a bash command. Any ideas what I'm missing, and how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: So I see you're installing Quartus II , which might be a bit old. Altera has newer version of its software, Quartus Prime, so I'd suggest to try installing that instead.   Also, I wouldn't call it with `bash` specifically, just run `sudo ./setup.sh` and let the script do the work, instead of imposing specific shell onto it.

Comment: Thanks @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, I'll try this soon. Just wanted to use a familiar environment for the moment.  Any ideas why I got the errors above for `sudo ./setup.sh`? 
I still couldn't resolve that one... checked executability, dos2unix and ownership!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a little faith in your ability to solve a problem and dig a little deeper!

By viewing (ie, using `vim setup.sh`) the shell file, a list of the dependencies it checks for could be btained. Inside the shell script, I found:

```
for item in libstdc++ glibc libX11 libXext libXau libXdmcp freetype fontconfig expat
```

Installed equivalent Ubuntu libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libc6:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxau-dev:i386 libxdmcp-dev:i386 libfreetype6:i386 fontconfig:i386 expat:i386
```

After viewing the script some more and recognized that the 32bit library dependence would print regardless of module existence from observing the shell code, I went back to the **actual error**, as above.

```
setup.sh: line .../QuartusSetupWeb-13.1.0.162.run: Permission denied
setup.sh: line 106 exec: ... 162.run: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

In particular, the commands using `bash setup.sh` or `sudo bash setup.sh` couldn't then execute the `.run` files, because of the permission properties of these files. A simple fix, allowing these listed files executable permission, solved all the problems.

```
chmod +x QuartusSetupWeb-13.1.0.162.run
```

Answer (score 1):

Check shebang interpreter directive, to see what sh interpreter are actually used for setup.sh.
In case of Quartus 9.0 it was 
`"#!/bin/csh"`
which indicates C-shell, not installed in Ubuntu by default.